Plot multiple interaction plots using sJplot::plot_model for multiple outcomes
I want to generate multiple interaction plots from multiple outcomes data using sjPlot::plot_model.
For example, I am using a dataset MathAchive from nlme and load these packages
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
library(broom.mixed)

My objectives are:

to run a regression model for outcomes MatchAch and SES one by one
top include in the model an interaction between Minority and Sex
then plot the interaction for outcomes MatchAch then SES

The results that I want should look like below but I want to apply DRY principle and would prefer using purrr::map
mod_math <- 
  lmer(MathAch ~ Minority*Sex + (1| School), 
             data = MathAchieve) 
plot_model(mod_math, type = "int")

mod_ses <- 
  lmer(SES ~ Minority*Sex + (1| School), 
       data = MathAchieve) 
plot_model(mod_ses, type = "int")

I could get multiple tidy results using purrr::map
MathAchieve |> 
  select(MathAch, SES) |>
  map(~ lmer(.x ~ Minority*Sex + (1| School), 
             data = MathAchieve)) |>
  map(~tidy(.x))

But I receive errors when using purrr::map like below
MathAchieve |> 
  select(MathAch, SES) |>
  map(~ lmer(.x ~ Minority*Sex + (1| School), 
             data = MathAchieve)) |>
  map(~ plot_model(.x, type = "int"))

MathAchieve |> 
  select(MathAch, SES) |>
  map(~ lmer(.x ~ Minority*Sex + (1| School), 
             data = MathAchieve) |>
        plot_model(., type = "int"))

What should I do to get multiple interaction plots from models with multiple outcomes?

One option to fix your issue would be to apply map on a vector of the outcome variable names and use reformulate to create the formula:
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
library(broom.mixed)
library(purrr)

c("MathAch", "SES") |>
  map(~ lmer(
    reformulate("Minority * Sex + (1 | School)", .x),
    data = MathAchieve
  )) |>
  map(~ plot_model(.x, type = "int")) |> 
  set_names(c("MathAch", "SES"))
#> $MathAch


#> 
#> $SES


